How do I increase max_new_tokens
I'm facing this error while running my code:

ValueError: Input length of input_ids is 1495, but max_length is set to 20. This can lead to unexpected behavior. You should consider increasing max_length or, better yet, setting max_new_tokens.

I wanted the code to generate the query instead it says about the max length issue as basically I am using 8 bit quantized llama using vector embedding to develop a RAG chat bot
import os
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from transformers import BitsAndBytesConfig, AutoTokenizer
from langchain_huggingface import ChatHuggingFace, HuggingFacePipeline
from time import time
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

# Load PDF and split into chunks
def split_doc(file, chunk_size, chunk_overlap):
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator="\n\n",
        chunk_size=chunk_size,
        chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap,
        length_function=len
    )
    return text_splitter.split_documents(file)

loader = PyPDFLoader("/kaggle/input/report/report.pdf")
pages = loader.load()
docs = split_doc(pages, 700, 450)

# Configure and load the model
model_name = "NousResearch/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_8bit=True)
llm = HuggingFacePipeline.from_model_id(
    model_id=model_name,
    task="text-generation",
    model_kwargs={"trust_remote_code": True, "quantization_config": bnb_config}
)
chat_model = ChatHuggingFace(llm=llm)

# Set up embeddings and vector store
embedding_model_name = "sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2"
embedding_model_kwargs = {"device": "cuda"}
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name=embedding_model_name, model_kwargs=embedding_model_kwargs)
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=docs, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory="chroma_db")
retriever = vectordb.as_retriever()

# Set up the QA system
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=retriever,
    verbose=True
)

# Define the testing function
def test_rag(qa, query):
    print(f"Query: {query}\n")
    result = qa.run(query)
    print("\nResult: ", result)

query = "What were the main topics in this "
test_rag(qa, query)# get stuck here


thanks it helped i added the following details:
using the pipeline_kwargs in huggingface.py file i was able to find the variable i could use although using this method will render the quantization method a bit useless as you will consume more memory upon increasing the tokens
llm = HuggingFacePipeline.from_model_id(
    model_id=model_name,
    task="text-generation",
    model_kwargs={
        "trust_remote_code": True,
        "quantization_config": bnb_config,
        "use_auth_token": auth_token
    },
    pipeline_kwargs={"max_new_tokens": 8096}# this part is how i reconfigured the tokens

)


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

The solution lies within the module itself. It's just you have to set pipeline_kwargs likewise
Example using from_model_id:
.. code-block:: python
        from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFacePipeline
        hf = HuggingFacePipeline.from_model_id(
            model_id="gpt2",
            task="text-generation",
            pipeline_kwargs={"max_new_tokens": 10},
        )
Example passing pipeline in directly:
    .. code-block:: python

        from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFacePipeline
        from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

        model_id = "gpt2"
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
        model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id)
        pipe = pipeline(
            "text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_new_tokens=10
        )
        hf = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)

